# How to implement Site Under Maintenance in Full stack Next and Express

Tags: express, next.js, production

I am making a full stack application with its frontend on Next and custom backend on Express. The application also has an admin dashboard. How do I implement the Site in Maintenance feature that can be changed through admin dashboard in production environments.

The ideal case when site goes under maintenance should be the APIs should respond accordingly(which can be implemented through Express middleware). But the main issue is where do I store the configuration/value for if the site is under maintenance.

Similarly for nextjs, if I have an api call in _app.ts, would it affect the speed and load time?

All this has to be implemented in production as well as development environment.

One approach I thought was storing it in .env but that would cause redundancy for frontend and backend and also cause issues in configuring it through admin dashboard. Another one was storing it in DB, but would it affect the optimization in NextJS if checked in _app.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, [Redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) is used to handle this case:

[more on redirects](https://blog.logrocket.com/redirects-next-js/)

> Redirects are frequently used in situations where a section of the
> site does not exist or is under construction, content has been moved
> to a different URL, the routing system has changed, users are being
> redirected due to access restrictions, or many other situations.

If you want to handle it through admin panel, you could keep track of page status in global state. for example you could have

```
const pageStatus={page1:false,page2:false,...}
```

if you want to put one of the pages under construction, you could set it to `true`

```
const pageStatus={page1:true,page2:false,...}
```

in page1, you could read the global state, and in case of maintenance, you could show a different ui

Comment: The admin panel is in a different repository, so I cannot have a global state. Also having a global state still wont disable the express apis. What can we do about it?